# Bootstrap Datepick - how to change font size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker but the calendar that comes up has a larger font size than I would like. It is the same font as the normal display but just one size larger, and I never specified any sizes so I would have expected it to use the default that I saw in all the examples. I've looked through the css file and other files but I can't figure out how to change this. What attribute do I use to change the font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
.datepicker { font-size: 13px; } /* or whatever other font size you want */
```

I tested that by doing a live edit on the website for Bootstrap Datepicker and it seemed to work.

Comment: It didn't recognize font-size
<label for="start">Start Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/datepicker.less" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datepicker').datepicker ({
      });
    </script>

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but that is CSS not JavaScript. You need to either put it at the bottom of an existing .css file (either in or after datepicker.css), or add it to your <head> by surrounding it with <style> and </style> Is that what you did? If it is, the quick fix is to make it font-size: 13px!important; instead.

Comment: perfect, I found somewhere to add it in the css file and it worked. thank you!